# bind 2 sql tables with grid view in mvc (database first)

Tags: c#, html, css, sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to create grid view in my app
 first I have view model :

**My view model**

[image]

**My controller code**

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    PropertyEntities1 Property_db = new PropertyEntities1();
         public ActionResult ReportUsers(UserGridViewViewModel userrr)
    {
        var resualt = (from person in Property_db.Person_TB join user in Property_db.User_TB on person.Person_ID equals user.User_ID select new { person.Person_ID , person.Name, person.LName, user.Username, user.Password }).ToList();

        return View(resualt);
    }
}
```

**My view code**

[image]

but it doesn't work 
what should i do?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: in view it dosent show any thing, i think it dosent map between usergridviewviewmodel with reture resualt